# Is rebooting necessary after oom-killer kills a user process?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is rebooting necessary after oom-killer is invoked on a user process (not a system critical process)?  Is there any chance of anything being in a bad state other than the user process that was killed.  From researching this question, it seems to be recommended to reboot after an OOM event, even if oom-killer only killed a user process.  I understand the need to reboot if oom-killer kills a random system process, but if it kills a user process, is there any chance of anything else being in a funky state?

Answer (score 2):

"it seems to be recommended to reboot"... that's a windows thing, seems to be recommended for just about anything. No, you don't need to reboot. But look into what caused the OOM condition -- was it the process that got killed, or is it that some other process(es) are starting to consume too much memory. Also, see if you may need to make some swap space available on that machine.